# How to determine of pumps required on a pipeline

Tags: design, pumps, hydraulics, pipelines

I have a 14km long pipe with total head loss of 113m, transporting water at 40m3/h. How do I decide how many pumps I need? I understand headloss is 113m, but I still don't get how does this tells me about number of pumps.

Comment: So how much  power is needed to overcome 1m of headloss?

Comment: One pump with enough discharge pressure.